# How can I remove parts of an NSURL and save the result to a NSString with format?

Tags: swift

How can I format `file:///Applications/App%20Store.app` to be stored as a string "App Store"? I want to remove everything before "App%20Store.app" and make it automatically add a space for the %20 in the new stored string.

My code takes user input from an `NSOpenPanel()` and saves the result shown above to an NSURL variable.

**EDIT** Got it working with this! Thanks

```
var URLinString : String = selectedApp!.absoluteString!

let newString = URLinString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file:///Applications/", withString: "")

let newerString = newString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%20", withString: " ")
```

Comment: Have a look at NSURL and NSURLComponents ...

Comment: let fileName =  "file:///Applications/App%20Store.app".stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!.lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension

Comment: @DanTdd Hopefully you will never get a file name with `%25` or `%26` or `%…`…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Objective-C

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Applications/App%20Store.app"];
NSString *lastComponent = [url lastPathComponent];
NSLog(@"Last path component:%@", lastComponent);
```

---

Swift

```
var url = NSURL(string:"file:///Applications/App%20Store.app")
var lastComponent = url?.lastPathComponent
println("\(lastComponent)")
if lastComponent == "App Store.app" {
  println("Yes")
}
```

Console

```
Optional("App Store.app")
Yes
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to tag this in Swift only.

Comment: Then you should only include `swift` tag not the `objective-c` tag

Comment: It makes the string Optional("App Store.app"), how could i get it to just say "App Store.app"?

I got it by just making a new var : String and assigning it to = LastComponent

Comment: Your `println()` is implemented in this way that it also shows that value is optional, I have added some more code to demonstrate that the value is `App Store.app`

Comment: `var nonOptional = lastComponent!` would also have done the trick. No need of `var : String and assigning it to = lastComponent`

Answer (score 2):

According to what you are saying, you want to retrieve the filename.

You can use [NSString class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html) methods (Edited thanks to comments)

In **Objective-C** :

```
NSURL *myNSURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Applications/App%20Store.app"];

//Extract filename and remove file extension
NSString* fileName = [[myNSURL lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

In **Swift** :

```
var myNSURL = NSURL(string:"file:///Applications/App%20Store.app")

//Extract filename and remove file extension
var fileName = myNSURL?.lastPathComponent?.stringByDeletingPathExtension
```

Comment: That not needed, you can use `lastPathComponent' of `NSURL` class

Comment: Sorry, I meant to tag this in Swift only.

Comment: @DanTdd I have edited, thanks also Inder Kumar Rathore for remarks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
let link = "file:///Applications/App%20Store.app"

extension String {
    var fileName : String {
        return stringByRemovingPercentEncoding?.lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension ?? ""
    }
}

print(link.fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = …;

NSString *escapedFileName = [url lastPathComponent];
NSString *fileName = [escapedFileName stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Typed in Safari.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to tag this in Swift only.